# Thrift converting optional to default or required

Tags: c++, thrift

I have a thrift struct

```
struct Message {
    1: optional int userID;
    ...
}
```

Is it a safe operation to change it to default require-ness?

```
struct Message {
    1: int userID;
    ...
}
```

If I know it's always set? What about "required"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a required thrift field optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558302/how-do-i-make-a-required-thrift-field-optional)

Comment: Why? I am asking the opposite: from optional to default.

Comment: Did you read the answer? No.

Comment: @JensG are you sure? I have an optional field and I simply remove optional (make it default), you think it's un-safe? Could you give one example where it will break?

Answer (score 4):

As outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558302/how-do-i-make-a-required-thrift-field-optional), there are three degrees of (so-called) requiredness in Thrift:

- `required`: must exist on read, must be set on write
- `optional`: may or may not be set, entirely optional
- "default": may not exist on read, always written (unless it is a `null` pointer )

To answer the question(s) asked:

1. It is safe to change `optional` to default (i.e. remove the `optional` keyword).
2. Changing `optional` to `required` may break compatibility. Unless you make sure all clients/servers are updated accordingly, it may happen that the older side does not supply a value for such a field. In that case, the other end will reject the incoming request or response as incomplete, because that `required` field is missing from the received data.

For further reading on the subject you may want to consult Diwaker Gupta's highly recommendable "[Missing Guide](https://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/#_defining_structs)".

Comment: Some very helpful context on default vs optional: https://grokbase.com/t/thrift/user/08azr2zpzv/default-required-optional