# Apache Thrift, FieldReq in parameter list?

Tags: thrift

Is there any difference in leaving FieldReq out, in comparison to specifying `required`? 
In the parameter list.

`optional` gives warning `optional keyword is ignored in argument lists.`, probably for my set of languages.

Answer (score 1):

Thrift does not support optional arguments. You may have `optional` fields in a `struct` and use the latter as argument:

```
struct MyArgs {
  1: required string req
  2: optional string opt
  3: string def  // this is called "default requiredness"
}

service Foobar {
   void DoSomething(1: MyArgs args)
}
```

The difference between the three options is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53420786/499466) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558302/how-do-i-make-a-required-thrift-field-optional).